# linq entity framework include weird behaviour

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have an issue with the linq query when I dont explicitly use include for a navigation property.

```
---Task entity model ----
...
 public Project Project { get; set; }
 public TaskType TaskType { get; set; }
...

var tasks = db.Tasks
        .Where(t => (t.Project.ProjectId == project.ProjectId))


foreach (Task t in tasks)
{
 // for some items t.TaskType is null   


// I have noticed that when t.TaskType.Id 
// is different to the first one in the loop then only the next different 
// tasktype is null

} 


// however when using 
var tasks = db.Tasks.Include(t=>t.TaskType)
        .Where(t => (t.Project.ProjectId == project.ProjectId))          
// tasktype is always there (where as without the include in some tasks it  does not extract the tasktype)
```

Using the .Include fixed my issue but I like to understand why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eager Loading in EF, then navigation properties not load with root object. `Include` method instruct EF, that navigation property should loaded with your root object.

With Lazy loading your navigation property loaded, when you call this property, so if you use lazy load, then `Include` method not necessary.

More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Would it eager load navigation properties for only some items and not others ? I step through foreach loop as above, and some tasks do not have tasktypes included. I would expect the behaviour of eager load to be consistent.

Comment: @wfquestions Before `var tasks = db.Tasks.Where(t => (t.Project.ProjectId == project.ProjectId))` query how you use `db` instance of `DbContext`? Maybe you add some `Tasks` in this `DbContext` instance?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is lazy load the related entities. To do that you need to specify your navigation properties as `virtual`. From this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx):

> Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of
>   entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that
>   a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed. When using
>   POCO entity types, lazy loading is achieved by creating instances of
>   derived proxy types and then overriding **virtual** properties to add the
>   loading hook.

When you specify the `virtual` keyword in your navigation properties, EF creates at runtime dynamic proxies for your entity classes. Those proxy classes are responsible for the lazy loading behavior of the related entities. Without virtual, lazy loading will not be supported, and you get null on your navigation properties. So you need to do this:

```
public class Task
{
   //...
   public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
   public virtual TaskType TaskType { get; set; }
{
```

In this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) you will find all the requiriments  you need to follow to support lazy loading.

Using the `Include` method you can eager load the related entities as part of the query.